# How to set Repeating Alarm in Android using Recurrence Picker Dialog?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am new to android developing, and i am working on Task Reminder App. I need to set repeating alarm for the task, and for that purpose, i am using Recurrence Picker Dialog.

But i don't know how to set multiple alarms based on the string returned by the recurrence picker dialog.

I am using the following recurrence picker dialog.

[image]

It returns a string in variable 'rrule', but i don't know how to use that string to set multiple alarms. Below is the code to set Listener for the picker.

```
recurrencePickerDialog.setOnRecurrenceSetListener(new RecurrencePickerDialog.OnRecurrenceSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRecurrenceSet(String rrule) {

                        }
                    });

recurrencePickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"recurrencePicker");
```

Anyone please help me. I would be thankful..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set alarms using [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and a Custom [Broadcast Receiver](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).
You can set your alarm like this.

```
 @Override
 public void onRecurrenceSet(String rrule) {

     if (rrule != null && rrule.length() > 0) {
        EventRecurrence recurrenceEvent = new EventRecurrence();
        recurrenceEvent.setStartDate(new Time("" + new Date().getTime()));
        recurrenceEvent.parse(rrule);

      //Sets alarm
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        long offset=getNextOccurence(recurrenceEvent);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+offset,pendingIntent);

       //Then save the rule somewhere.


     } else {
      Lod.d("TEST","No recurrence");
     }
   }
```

**getNextOccurrence** function

```
 /**
 * Get the milliseconds till next alarm
 * @param e
 * @return
 */
private long getNextOccurrence(EventRecurrence e) {
    switch (e.freq) {
        case EventRecurrence.HOURLY://When alarm is hourly
            if(e.interval==0)//When set to 1 Hour
                return 1000 * 60 * 60;
            return 1000 * 60 * 60 * e.interval;
        // TODO: Implement cases for other frequencies 


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then, in your Broacast Receiver, do the following:

1. Show Alarm
2. Set next alarm to be on next occurrence (based on saved rule)

Hope this helps you to get started.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. can you please tell me how i can set recurring alarm untill a specific date or for a number of events? These are two options other than 'Forever' option shown in above image.

Comment: Since you are having different intervals between alarms, you may simply recalculate time till next occurrence of alarm and set the alarm within the Broadcast Receiver.